# python convert a list to a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert a list of lists to a list of dicts, the list is like,

```
['A', '100000', Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), '003']
['B', '100001', Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), '004']
```

I want to convert it to a list of dicts like,

```
{'name': 'A', 'id': '100000', 'time': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'number': '003'}
{'name': 'B', 'id': '100001', 'time': Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), 'number': '004'}
```

I am wondering what's the best way to do it.

Comment: What did you try? A list comprehension would seem to be the obvious thing.

Comment: what have you tried you're not happy with?

Answer (score 1):

Using dict comprehension and `zip()`:

```
a = ['A', '100000', Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), '003']
b = ['B', '100001', Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), '004']

all_lists = [a, b]

keys = ['name', 'id', 'time', 'number']

d = {key: val for a_list in all_lists for key, val in zip(keys, a_list)}  # using dict comprehension
```

Comment: `dict(zip(keys, a))`

Comment: But the source is a list of lists, and the destination should be a list of dicts. So it should just be `[dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in list_of_lists]`.

Comment: this only answers one part of the question ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers it is true, but then the question is missing a mcve too.